# Upper back exercise on the road

Tags: upper-body-workout, bodyweight

What are good exercises for upper back which you can preform in the hotel room?

I only have my bodyweight and that's it. Also, I'm not very keen to test the strength of the various hotel's bars/rods by preforming pull-ups / chin-ups on them.

Comment: Take a towel, wrap it around the doorknob, do "rows", or put it on the door (from the top) and close the door, do "rows". I think Ross Enamait has some more ideas, check his website.

Answer (score 2):

There's two products I would recommend (I hate to push a product, but these are relatively cheap and effective):

- http://fitdeck.com/ - a set of exercise cards developed by a Navy Seal with the idea of working out in a limited space.  The basic set will keep you busy and provide a full body workout and they also expanded their products...
- http://www.bodylastics.com/ - a rubber band system with interchangeable bands for resistance.  Not as cheap, but gives resistance training via a very easy to carry case.

Specific for the back, I would agree with VPeric - using a towel on doorknobs, I would also recommend looking at Ross Enimait's homemade isometric tool/workout: http://rosstraining.com/blog/2009/02/23/homemade-isometric-tool/  Isometrics are VERY effective and with this device there's a wide range of back exercises (specific to your question) that you can do.

Comment: TRX and all the similar fixed rope systems can work over doors.

Answer (score 1):

As a guy that's on month 4 of living in hotels, I'd add 2 others. The doorknob rows are super useful, too.

Bathroom door pullups. This was weird at first, but I've gotten used to it. Before you attempt these, slide something under the door to stabilize it. I also like to throw a towel over the top of the door.

Under the desk rows. 80% of the rooms I stay in have a desk. Move the desk out where you have some room. Slide yourself under it lengthwise. Grab bith sides of the desk and pull yourself up.